# call another ajax if the result of previous ajax is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want call another ajax if the result of previous ajax is true.
I had used **if else** statment inside success function of previous ajax,
but in my case if the result of previous ajax is **true** or **false** and then the next ajax still not be proccess, just only run `$('.captcha-error1').fadeIn(1000).delay(900).fadeOut();`.

PHP code :

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $datacode = $_SESSION["6_letters_code"];
  $datacaptcha = $_POST['6_letters_code'];
  if($datacode !== $datacaptcha){
    echo json_encode("false");
  }else{
    echo json_encode("true");
  }
?>
```

this is my javascript code :

```
var captchaCode;
captchaCode = $('#6_letters_code').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "php/captcha/validateCaptcha.php",
    data : captchaCode,
    success : function(hasil) {
        if(hasil == 'true'){
            console.log("if is "+hasil);
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "php/contact.php",
                data : contactForm.serialize(),
                success : function(result) {
                    if (result == 'true') {
                        contactForm.stop().animate({opacity : '0'}, 400, function() {
                            contactForm.css('display', 'none');
                            $('#success').css('display', 'block');
                            $('#success').stop().animate({opacity : '1'}, 900);
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#error').css('display', 'block');
                        $('#error').stop().animate({opacity : '1'}, 1000);
                        alert('Error Message: ' + result);
                    }
                },
                error : function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#error').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#error').stop().animate({opacity : '1'}, 1000);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });//ajax II
        }else{
            console.log("else is "+hasil);
            $('.captcha-error1').fadeIn(1000).delay(900).fadeOut();
        }
    }
});//ajax I
```

Comment: If the `else` block is running then clearly the condition evaluated to `false`.  What is *actually* in the `hasil` variable?

Comment: You can to write your handlers outside of calls. It's callback hell, what I see...

Comment: 1. This totally breaks the captcha security, as anyone can just post directly to contact.php 2. What exactly gets returned from validateCaptcha.php?

Comment: the hasil variable is true and right @David

Comment: Why would you need 2 sequential ajax requests to the same server? Just do 1 and have it return json with the detailed information that you need to do what you do now.

Comment: You are fight with humans, not with bots with this captcha... :(

Comment: @Ariasa: Well, you say that.  But the results of the code don't lie.  JavaScript isn't trying to *trick* you.  This condition is evaluating to false: `hasil == 'true'`  Therefore, `hasil` *does not equal* `'true'`.

Comment: the returned from validateCaptcha.php is **true** and **right** string variable @Steve

Comment: Change your console.log in the if clause to `console.log('its true: ' +hasil);` and in the else clause to `console.log('its false: ' +hasil);` . I bet you see something like `Its false: true`

Comment: For a proper answer you are going to need to show the contents of `validateCaptcha.php` but im 99% sure its just because you have an extra space somewhere, so `hasil` actually == `  true` or similar. You should return json not just a string to avoid this type of problem.

Comment: I repeat: your implementation is **wrong** on the design level. This can not to stop the bots, but can to stop your users. Just **remove** captcha at all. It'll be better.

Comment: Though the whole issue is mute considering the captcha is implemented in a way that any spam bot can bypass, so it only serves to annoy humans

Comment: I think, your `hasil == '"true"'` :) it's `json_encode`d string, which you forget to parse. You also forget `application/json` header, it's because jQuery can't to do it for you.

Comment: validateCaptcha.php is work normally, but now i only confused about how to proccess ajax contact.php if the result of previous ajax is true.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your server-side code emits:

```
if($datacode !== $datacaptcha){
    echo json_encode("salah");
}else{
    echo json_encode("benar");
}
```

And this is what your client-side code is looking for:

```
if(hasil == 'true')
```

The words "benar" and "true" may mean the same thing *to you*, but they are *not* the same string values.  Your computer isn't going to translate between languages for you.

Check for the string you're actually returning:

```
if(hasil == 'benar'){
```

Comment: sorry, i had update the code, please check above

Comment: @Ariasa: What is the result of the updated code?  Is it still failing?  Where/how does it fail?

Comment: when the result of previous ajax is **true** or **false** then the next ajax still not proccess.<br> can you tell me the right code ?

Comment: @Ariasa: You need to debug this.  Nobody here can do that for you.  If your conditional statement is evaluating to `false` then *the condition is false*.  The runtime value of `hasil` ***is not*** `'true'`.  You might *think* it is, it may even indeed be *very similar*.  But it is *not* equal.  We can't debug this on your computer for you.  You need to do that.  We can tell you why some particular piece of code may behave a certain way.  But `hasil == 'true'` is a *very* simple piece of code.  It does exactly *one* thing.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use strings for boolean checks, send an actual boolean:

```
session_start();
$datacode = $_SESSION["6_letters_code"];
$datacaptcha = $_POST['6_letters_code'];
//set correct header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['captchaMatch'=> $datacode==$datacaptcha]);
```

in your js:

```
success : function(hasil) {
    if(hasil.captchaMatch){
        ....
```

However this is really irrelevent as the design its self is broken - any bot can simply post directly to `contact.php` thus bypassing the captcha.

Instead have one ajax request direct to contact.php:

```
$('#yourformid').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.post('php/contact.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response){
        if(response.success){
            //show thanks message, hide form etc
        }else{
            $.each(response.errors, function(index, error){
                //show errors
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And in contact.php, check the captcha code and respond accordingly:

```
session_start();
$success = true;
$errors = [];
$datacode = $_SESSION["6_letters_code"];
$datacaptcha = $_POST['6_letters_code'];
if(!$datacode == $datacaptcha){
    $success = false;
    $errors[]= 'Captcha is wrong';
}
//the rest of your form handling code here.
//you can add other errors such as missing fields etc to the errors array
//then send response

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['success'=> $success, 'errors'=>$errors]);
```

Comment: thx steve, you are inspiring me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Finally i fix the problem.

this is my validateCaptcha.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
$datacode = $_SESSION["6_letters_code"];
$datacaptcha = $_POST['6_letters_code'];
$captchaResponse = 'true';

try{

    if($datacode !== $datacaptcha){
        $captchaResponse = 'false';
    }

    echo json_encode($captchaResponse);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
?>
```

and in my js there are no edited.
the problem fixed by used `try{....}catch(e){...}`
Thx to all, your great an expert people.